# What is the idiomatic Rust way to copy/clone a vector in a parameterized function?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a parameterized function that takes an immutable vector, clones or copies it, does something to the new vector (such as shuffle it) and returns it as a new owned vector.  How can this be done and what is the most idiomatic way to do it?

**Attempt #1**

```
pub fn shuffle<T>(vec: &mut [T]) {
    // ... contents removed: it shuffles the vector in place
    // ... so needs a mutable vector
}

pub fn shuffle_create_new<T: Clone>(vec: &[T]) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut newvec = vec.clone();
    shuffle(&mut newvec);
    return newvec.to_owned();
}
```

Fails with:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
8 |     shuffle(&mut newvec);
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

even though I declared `newvec` as mutable.  I don't understand why.

**Attempt #2**

```
pub fn shuffle_owned<T: Clone>(mut vec: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
    shuffle(&mut vec);
    return vec;
}
```

While this compiles, it doesn't do what I want.  The vector you pass into `shuffle_owned` gets **moved** into the function, shuffled and then has its ownership transferred back to the caller (via the return value).  So the original vector is *modified*.

I want to know how to pass in a vector that will **not** be mutated, but have the values cloned into a new boxed vector and returned when finished - as you do in a functional programming language that has immutable data (such as Clojure).

Comment: `to _owned` clones every element of `[T]` so it requires `T` to implement Clone (`<T: Clone>`)

Comment: Yes, that explains the error. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer, as your suggestion fixed the first error, but I still haven't figured out how to accomplish my overall goal.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Your attempt #1 is almost correct, you just have to move `to_owned()` to the first line:

```
fn shuffle<T>(vec: &mut [T]) {
    // ...
}

fn shuffle_create_new<T: Clone>(vec: &[T]) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut newvec = vec.to_vec();
    shuffle(&mut newvec);
    newvec
}
```

This happens because calling `clone()` on a slice will return you a slice (i.e. `&[T]`), and you cannot go from `&[T]` to `&mut [T]` because you cannot choose mutability of a reference (borrowed pointer). When you call `to_owned()`, however, you are getting a fresh instance of `Vec<T>` and you can put it into a mutable variable to get mutable vector.

As of Rust 1.0, either [`slice::to_vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.to_vec) or [`to_owned()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#tymethod.to_owned) method from the `ToOwned` trait can be used to create `Vec<T>` from `&[T]`.

There are also now several ways to obtain `&mut [T]` from `Vec<T>`: the slicing notation (`&mut vec[..]`), the deref conversion (`&mut *vec`) or the direct method call (`vec.as_mut_slice()`, though this one is deprecated):

Comment: According to [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_mut_slice) method `vec.as_mut_slice()` is not deprecated.

Answer (score 23):

This is probably what you want:

```
pub fn copy_shuffle<T: Clone>(vec: &Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut vec = vec.clone();
    shuffle(&mut vec);
    vec
}
```

or

```
pub fn copy_shuffle<T: Clone>(vec: &[T]) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut vec = vec.to_vec();
    shuffle(&mut vec);
    vec
}
```

Comment: You're right this works too - thanks for the tip on that type of construct!  The difference between your answer and the one from @Vladimir is that when you call it you have to take the address: `copy_shuffle(&myvec)` vs. `shuffle_create_new(myvec)`.  I'm guessing that Vladimir's version is more idiomatic Rust, but I'm not really sure. I'll accept his answer, but let the community tell me if I'm wrong by the number of upvotes.

Comment: @quux00, you're quite right. In case of `&~[T]` you have two levels of indirection (I'm not sure, maybe LLVM can optimize it away in the executing code, but they are still there on semantic level), with `&[T]` or `~[T]` there is only one. However, sometimes this is the only way it could work, for example, when implementing generic traits like `Add<X, Y>`, at least until unsized types (like `[T]`) are added to the language.